# How to prevent Heroku from clearing the indexes built by acts_as_indexed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, full-text-search

I am using acts_as_indexed gem for full text search for my rails app deployed on heroku.Acts_as_indexed builds the indexes for the searches. My problem is Heroku clears the indexes after some time. Is there any way for preventing Heroku to do so? or I am also trying to implement texticle instead of acts_as_indexed.Is it really good to use? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku only allows write access in the tmp directory of your application, and the contents are not guaranteed to persist - whenever you restart or redeploy the application, they will go away. This is not something you can prevent, you'll need to find another way of implementing the text search on Heroku, maybe using one of their search addons listed at http://addons.heroku.com/ .

Comment: To expand on that, I believe the app's filesystem will be cleared out at least daily.